# Disable Facebook auto sync in Android 4.4

Tags: sync, 4.4-kitkat, facebook

Can I disable facebook auto sync in Android 4.4?

I could easily do this for my Google account, but I see no options to disable Facebook auto sync in Settings->Accounts->Facebook.

Comment: You might find the options inside the Facebook app itself.

Comment: I'll post that as the answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sync options are located within the Facebook app itself in Settings.

For example, photo sync options are located under `Account > App Settings > Sync Photos`.